# Moment Timezone ("America/Los Angeles") off by 3 minutes

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I wrote a function to return the current time in PST/PDT in HH:MM A format 
(e.g. 12:04 AM)

```
function getTimeStr() {
  var currentTime = moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format("hh:mm a").toUpperCase();
  if(currentTime.charAt(0) === '0') {
    currentTime = currentTime.substr(1);
  }
  return currentTime;
}
```

However, moment-timezone returns the time 3 minutes off the correct time.

On their website http://momentjs.com/timezone/ the time is correct, but not when I call the function.

For example, if it's 4:07 PM , I'll receive 4:04 PM.

I'm wrote this in node and the code running on an AWS EC2 Instance.

Comment: Is the time of the machine correct? Doesn't seem like it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AWS server is not inherently the correct time

https://www.garron.me/en/linux/set-time-date-timezone-ntp-linux-shell-gnome-command-line.html

Comment: Should that matter? I'm calling a third party API via moment-timezone.

Comment: moment works using the time of the machine it's on - so, yes.

Comment: What do you mean @imchingy? The moment-timezone code is running on your ec2 instance and thusly instantiating a new momentjs instance takes the time from that server

Comment: Ah I see. How do you suggest matching the correct time inside my server with PST/PDT?

Comment: You won't, you'll set the server time to UTC, but you'll do it with the info at the link I pasted above. It's the code you're using here in Node that will do the conversion from UTC to PST/PDT